# what youtube embed is more accessible for users w/ screenreaders/only keyboards

Tags: accessibility, video

I notice that Youtube now likes to embed videos using an Iframe, but will still allow the old object method.

I'm just curious which method would be best for people using the site in an unconventional way, like with a screenreader or keyboard-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://dltj.org/article/standards-compliant-web-video/ and this one from A List Apart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed.

Additionally, for accessibility with IFrames, check out this resource: http://www.contentquality.com/tutorial/a11.htm#seven

Finally, WCAG has it's own recommendations for dealing with frames in general: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-WCAG20-HTML-TECHS-20031209/#frames

I would not be surprised if a screen reader did not support frames at all.  It is rather difficult to infer a proper tab order as you are essentially only visually combining multiple separate pages.

As far as keyboard-only access, the flash player (or [JavaScript player](http://videojs.com/) for HTML5) needs to have keyboard accelerators for the all important buttons.  For example, Play/Pause are usually activated by the [space] bar.  You can bind the ',' and '.' as well as '<' and '>' to reverse and fast forward functions (on US keyboards it's the same key).  Volume controls can use the '-' and '=' as well as '_' and '+' (same keys).  Video players vary too much for me to offer any more suggestions after this.  Just know that the Flash player has to implement these keyboard accelerators so there is nothing you can do to extend it.  The JavaScript player is a bit more open.